# ModelState validation fails when the CheckBox is unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

**In the view:**

```
@model  MvcDNC.Models.clsDSAMaster
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "wfrmDSAMaster";

    var grid = new WebGrid( Model.DSAList,canPage: true, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 10);
    int rowVal = 0;
}
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward(1);
    function NumbersOnly() {
        //alert(event.keyCode);
        if (((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) && event.keyCode != 8) {
            alert("Enter Numbers only");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@ViewBag.flag' == 'edit') {
            $("#tblfooterbtn").css('display', 'none');
            $("#tblDSADisp").css('display', 'none');
            $("#pnlNewDSA").css('display', 'block');
            $("#update").css('display', 'block');
            $("#save").css('display', 'none');

        }
        var count = 0;

        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            var text = $("#ddlFieldName option:selected").text();
            $("#ddlFieldName option:selected").val(text);
        });

        $("#btnAddDSA").click(function () {

            $("#tblfooterbtn").css('display', 'none');
            $("#tblDSADisp").css('display', 'none');
            $("#pnlNewDSA").css('display', 'block');
            $(':input', '#form0').removeAttr('selected').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');
            $('#Insert_DSA_ChkFlag').prop('checked', true);
        });

        $("#btnCancel").click(function () {

            $("#tblfooterbtn").css('display', 'block');
            $("#tblDSADisp").css('display', 'block');
            $("#pnlNewDSA").css('display', 'none');
        });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //            $("#tblfooterbtn").css('display', 'block');
            //            $("#tblDSADisp").css('display', 'block');
            //            $("#pnlNewDSA").css('display', 'none');
            validateBANID();

        });

        $("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
            $("#tblfooterbtn").css('display', 'block');
            $("#tblDSADisp").css('display', 'block');
            $("#pnlNewDSA").css('display', 'none');

        });

        $(".btnEdit").click(function () {
            var _strDSAID = ($(this).parent().siblings(':first').next()).html();

            window.location.href = "/DSA/GetDSADetails?id=" + _strDSAID;

        });

        $(".btnChangeStatus").click(function () {
            var changeStatus = $(this);
            var edit = $(this).prev();
            changeStatus.prop("disabled", true);
            edit.prop("disabled", true);
            var _strDSAID = ($(this).parent().siblings(':first').next()).html();
            var _strStatus = ($(this).parent().siblings(':first').next().next().next().next()).text();

            $.post("UpdateDSAStatus", { id: _strDSAID, Status: _strStatus }, function (data, changeStatus, edit) {
                $("#lblError").html(data);
            });

        });

        $("#Insert_DSA_CountryCode").change(function () {
            var country = this.value;

            $.post("GetLocations", { Location: country, Type: "country" }, function (data) {

                $("#Insert_DSA_StateCode").html(data);


            });
        });

        $("#Insert_DSA_StateCode").change(function () {
            var state = this.value;
            $.post("GetLocations", { Location: state, Type: "state" }, function (data) {
                $("#Insert_DSA_CityCode").html(data);

            });
        });
        $("body").on('click', '.btnAddMore', function () {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(this).remove();
            parent.after('<div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%"><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><input type="text"/></div><button class= "btnAddMore" style="left:0px;position:relative;">Add More</button></div>');
        });


        $("#Insert_DSA_RSMId").blur(function () {
            var id = this.value;
            $.post("GetSM_ASM_RSM", { id: id, Type: "RSM" }, function (data) {
                data = data.toString();
                var result = data.split(',');
                $("#Insert_DSA_RSMName").val(result[0]);
                $("#hdnRsmID").val(result[1]);
                $("#Insert_DSA_RSMEmail").val(result[2]);

            });
        });

        $("#Insert_DSA_ASMId").blur(function () {
            var id = this.value;
            $.post("GetSM_ASM_RSM", { id: id, Type: "ASM" }, function (data) {
                data = data.toString();
                var result = data.split(',');
                $("#Insert_DSA_ASMName").val(result[0]);
                $("#hdnASmID").val(result[1]);
                $("#Insert_DSA_ASMEmail").val(result[2]);

            });

        });

        $("#Insert_DSA_SMId").blur(function () {
            var id = this.value;
            $.post("GetSM_ASM_RSM", { id: id, Type: "SM" }, function (data) {
                data = data.toString();
                var result = data.split(',');
                $("#Insert_DSA_SMName").val(result[0]);
                $("#hdnSmID").val(result[1]);
                $("#Insert_DSA_SMEmail").val(result[2]);

            });

        });


    });
    function OnSuccess(data) {

        $("#lblError").html(data);
    }

    function OnFailure(response) {
//        alert("There was an error in adding DSA");
    }
    function validateBANID()
    {
        var vRSM = document.getElementById('Insert_DSA_RSMId').value;
        var vASM = document.getElementById('Insert_DSA_ASMId').value;
        var vSM = document.getElementById('Insert_DSA_SMId').value;
        if (vRSM == '' && vASM == '' && vSM == '') {
            alert('Two out of these three are compulsory');
            return false;
        }
        else if (vRSM != '' && vASM == '' && vSM == '') {
            alert('Two out of these three are compulsory');
            return false;
        }
        else if (vRSM == '' && vASM != '' && vSM == '') {
            alert('Two out of these three are compulsory');
            return false;
        }
        else if (vRSM == '' && vASM == '' && vSM != '') {
            alert('Two out of these three are compulsory');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<center>

<div class="container" id="tblDSADisp">
    <div class="header3">
            <center>@Html.Label("lblHeading", "DSA Master") </center> 
    </div><br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("wfrmDSAMaster", "DSA", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DSAMaster" }))
    {
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
               @Html.Label("lblFieldName", "Field Name :")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlFieldName", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                                                new SelectListItem{ Text="DSA ID", Value = "DDM_DSAID" ,Selected=true}, 
                                                new SelectListItem{ Text="DSA NAME", Value = "DDM_DSANAME" },
                                                new SelectListItem{ Text="COMPANY", Value = "DDM_COMPANYNAME" },
                                                new SelectListItem{ Text="WORKPHONE", Value = "DDM_WORKPHONE" },
                                                new SelectListItem{ Text="OUTBOUND NO", Value = "DDP_PHONENO" }
                })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                @Html.Label("lblKeyword", "Keyword:")
             </div>  
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBox("txtkeyword", "")
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlRoleNames", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "hidden" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                @Html.Label("lblCriteria", "Criteria :")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlCriteria", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                                            new SelectListItem{ Text="Exact Match", Value = "Exact_Match" ,Selected=true} ,
                                            new SelectListItem{ Text="Any", Value = "Any" } 
                })
            </div>
           <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" runat="server" class="button" value="Search" name="command" text="Search"/>   
            </div>

    </div>   
    }
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <label id="lblSearchError" style = "color:Red" ></label>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div class="row">
       @if (Model.DSAList.Count != 0)
       {
         @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                    headerStyle: "header3",
                    footerStyle: "header3",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                    selectedRowStyle: "select",
                                                   columns: grid.Columns(
                                          grid.Column("Sr.No.", format: item => rowVal = rowVal + 1),
                                          grid.Column("DSAID", "DSA ID"),
                                          grid.Column("DSANAME", "DSA Name"),
                                          grid.Column("COMPANYNAME", "Company"),
                                          grid.Column("STATUS", format: (item) =>
                                          {
                                              if (item.STATUS == "1")
                                              {
                                                  return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text>Active</text>"));
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text>Inactive</text>"));
                                              }
                                          }




                                          ),
                                          grid.Column("", format: (item) =>
                                          {
                                              if (item.locked == "Y")
                                              {


                                                  return Html.Raw(string.Format("<button class='btnEdit' style='width:50px' disabled>Edit</button>&nbsp; <button class='btnChangeStatus' disabled>Change Status</button>&nbsp;"));
                                              }
                                              else 
                                              {
                                                  return Html.Raw(string.Format("<button class='btnEdit' style='width:50px'>Edit</button>&nbsp; <button class='btnChangeStatus' >Change Status</button>&nbsp;"));
                                              }
                                          }


                        )))
       }
       @if (Model.DSAList.Count == 0)
       {
        @Html.Label("lblhstry", "NO RECORD EXISTS", new { style = "Font-Size:Small" })
       }
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="display:none">
         <input id="hdnSearchFlag" runat="server" name="hdnSearchFlag" type="hidden" visible="false" /> 
    </div>
</div>   

<div class="container" id="tblfooterbtn" >
        <button ID="btnAddDSA" runat="server"  class = "button">Add DSA</button><br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label id="lblError" style = "Width:100%; font-weight:bold; color:red"></label>
</div> 
<div class="container rowcolor1" id="pnlNewDSA" style="border:1px solid;width:60%;display:none" >
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save","DSA",
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{
    <div class="header3"  style="left:-15px;position:relative;width:105%">
            <center>@Html.Label("LblHeader", "DSA Details") </center> 
    </div><br />

    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblDSAID", "DSA ID")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.DSAId, new { @maxlength = "10" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.DSAId)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblDSANAME", "DSA NAME")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtDSANAME", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:100" })*@
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Firstname, new { @maxlength = "100" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Firstname)
          </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblDSACMPNY", "DSA COMPANY")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtDSANAME", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:100" })*@
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Company, new { @maxlength = "70" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Company)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblEMAILID", "EMAIL ID")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtEMAILID", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:70" })*@
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Email_Off, new { @maxlength=70 })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Email_Off)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblADDRESS1", "ADDRESS1")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Address1, new {@maxlength=45 })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Address1)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblADDRESS2", "ADDRESS2")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtADDRESS2", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:45" })*@
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Address2, new { @maxlength = 45 })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Address2)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblADDRESS3", "ADDRESS3")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtADDRESS3", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:45" })*@
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Address3, new { @maxlength = 45 })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblPIN", "PIN")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.TextBox("txtPin", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:6" })*@
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.PinCode, new { @maxlength = 6 })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.PinCode)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblCOUNTRY", "COUNTRY")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", Model.lstCountry, new { style = "width:150px" })*@
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.CountryCode, Model.lstCountry, new { style = "width:150px" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.CountryCode)
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblSTATE", "STATE")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          @*@Html.DropDownList("ddlState", Model.lstState, new { style = "width:150px" })*@
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.StateCode, Model.lstState, new { style = "width:150px" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.StateCode)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblCity", "CITY")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
         @* @Html.DropDownList("ddlCity", Model.lstCity, new { style = "width:150px" })*@
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.CityCode, Model.lstCity, new { style = "width:150px" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.CityCode)
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblWORKPHONE", "WORK PHONE")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       @* @Html.TextBox("txtWORKPHONE", "", new { style = "AutoCompleteType:disabled; MaxLength:11" })*@
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Office, new { @maxlength = 11 })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Office)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblmobile", "MOBILE")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Mobile, new { @maxlength = 10 })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="phone" class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <label id="lblTELEPHONENOs">TELEPHONE NOs</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @*<input type="text" name="txtTELEPHONENOs" id="txtTELEPHONENOs"/>*@
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Residence, new { @maxlength = 11 })
        </div>
        <button class= "btnAddMore" style="left:0px;position:relative;">Add More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblPRODUCTHANDLED", "PRODUCT HANDLED")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @*@Html.ListBox("lstbxProduct", Model.lstProduct, new { style = "width:150px" })*@
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ProductID, Model.lstProduct)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ProductID)
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblACTIVEUSER", "ACTIVE USER")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Active, "1", new { Checked = "checked" }) Yes</label><br />
        <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.Active, "0") No </label>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblEmp", "Enter Employee Number Of:")
        <font color="red">*</font>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        @Html.Label("lblRSM", "RSM")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        @Html.Label("lblASM", "ASM")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        @Html.Label("lblSM", "SM")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <br />
        @Html.Label("lblComp", "Two out of these three are compulsory")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <br />
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.RSMId, new { @maxlength = 50 })
        <input type="hidden" id="hdnRsmID" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ASMId, new { @maxlength = 50 })
          <input type="hidden" id="hdnASmID" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.SMId, new { @maxlength = 50 })
         <input type="hidden" id="hdnSmID" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.RSMName, new { @maxlength = 50 })
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.RSMEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ASMName, new { @maxlength = 50 })
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ASMEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.SMName, new { @maxlength = 50 })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.SMEmail)
        </div>        

    </div>
    <div class="row" style="left:-5px;position:relative;text-align:left; width:80%">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.Label("lblPassword", "Change Password At 1st Login", "SM")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ChkFlag, new {@checked="checked" })<b>Check this if you want to change password at first login</b>
        </div>
         @*<label style="left:-15px;position:relative;">Check this if you want to change password at first login</label>*@
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="save" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align:Right">
        <input name="submit"id="btnSubmit" class="buttons" type="submit" value="Save" style="height:22px ;width:50px"/>
        </div>
        <div id="update" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display:none;text-align:Right">
        <input name="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="buttons" type="submit" value="Update" style="height:22px ;width:50px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align:left">
        <button id="btnCancel" class="buttons" style="height:22px ;width:50px" >Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

</div>
</center>
```

**In the model:**

```
  public class Insert_DSA
    {
        public string[] ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public string ASMId { get; set; }
        public string ASMName { get; set; }
        public string ASMEmail { get; set; }
        public string RSMId { get; set; }
        public string RSMName { get; set; }
        public string RSMEmail { get; set; }
        public string SMId { get; set; }
        public string SMName { get; set; }
        public string SMEmail { get; set; }
        //public string UserId { get; set; }
        public bool  ChkFlag { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Pending { get; set; }

}
```

**In the controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(Models.clsDSAMaster MyModel,string submit)
        {

            int ucount = 0;
            string data = "";
            var form=Request.Form["Insert_DSA.ChkFlag"].ToString();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (submit == "Save")
                {
                    ucount = MyModel.Insert_DSA.addDSA(MyModel.Insert_DSA, Session["EmpCode"].ToString());
                    if (ucount > 0)
                    {
                        data = "Records have been sent to Checker and will be in effect post approval";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = "There was an error in adding DSA";
                    }

                }
                else if (submit == "Update")
                {
                    MyModel.Insert_DSA.UpdateDSA(MyModel.Insert_DSA, Session["EmpCode"].ToString());
                    if (ucount > 0)
                    {
                        data = "Records have been sent to Checker and will be in effect post approval";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = "There was an error in adding DSA";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors });
            }
                return Content(data, "text/html");
        }
```

there's no validation of any sort for this checkbox done manually by me,but still when the correctly validated data is posted to the controller `ModelState.IsValid` property is`false` if the checkbox is unchecked.
When i looked for the ModelState errors using

```
var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors });
```

it gives me

> The ChkFlag field is required.

**What I want:**
I don't want the checkbox to be a required field and I want `ModelState.IsValid` property to be true even when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: It will be valid - the form will post back either `true` of `false` and it will always be valid unless your doing something else in your code to prevent it. Are you posting this using ajax?

Comment: well, dont you want to use `<input type="checkbox"/>` insteadof `CheckBoxFor()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry got held up in a meeting couldn't respond in time.Yes i'm using an ajax form.

Comment: You need to show the details. That error could only be added if your actually posting back a value which is not either `true` or `false` (which is what the default will do)

Comment: @GeneR its easier to bind the model property using CheckBoxFor().

Comment: i've set the default property of the checkbox as checked like this  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Insert_DSA.ChkFlag, new {@checked="checked" })

Comment: That make no difference but you should not be doing it anyway. Its the value of the property which determines if the checkbox is checked or not (if `Insert_DSA.ChkFlag = true` it will be checked, otherwise it wont be)

Comment: then use nullable Boolean in your model: `bool? ChkFlag {get;set;}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke let me see if i'm missing something, i'll get back to you in a while.

Comment: @GeneR i'll give it a shot, i wonder what difference would it make?

Comment: @psylogic, It wont make any difference! And then your `CheckBoxFor()` method would not work anyway - don't waste your time. Its your javascript/ajax that is the problem

Comment: @GeneR Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). that's what I get for using nullable bool!

Comment: nullable properties of model are not required, until required attribute set. Convert this way: `var test = ChkFlag ?? false;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke the Modelstate error still persists despite the fact that the checkbox value sent to the controller is false

Comment: also the value sent to the controller is false even when the checkbox is checked

Comment: Nonsense (you are **NOT** sending either `true` or `false`). Show the relevant code!

Comment: @StephenMuecke check the edit! that's all the relevant code . Also i'll be posting the snapshots in a while as a proof !

Comment: It not the relevant code - you have already stated your using ajax to post the data. And to prove it, just use a standard `Html.BeginForm()` and standard submit button.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is there a way to make it work using Ajax.BeginForm , because everything works but this checkbox!

Comment: Yes of course. Using `Ajax.BeginForm()` is not your problem. There is something else you have not shown us that is causing you to post back a value which is not either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke check the edit and go through the snapshots!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96656/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-psylogic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$("#btnAddDSA").click(function () {` script, you have the following

```
$(':input', '#form0').removeAttr('selected').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');
```

which is changing the value of the checkbox from `value="True"` to `value=""`

Now if the checkbox is checked, instead of the form data being

```
...&Insert_DSA.ChkFlag=True&Insert_DSA.ChkFlag=False
```

its posting back

```
...&Insert_DSA.ChkFlag=&Insert_DSA.ChkFlag=False
```

Note that `Insert_DSA.ChkFlag=False` is a result of the `CheckBoxFor()` method generating an associated hidden input with `value="False"`

Now when the `DefaultModelBinder` reads the form values, it finds the first match for property `Insert_DSA.ChkFlag` and attempts to set it to an empty (`null`) value (the equivalent of `bool ChkFlag = null;`) which of course fails because a `bool` can only have a value of `true` or `false`. As a result the value of your property is its default (`false`) because its value cannot be set, and a `ModelState` error is added.

It's unclear what the purpose of this code is, but one way to solve it would be to exclude `input[type="checkbox"]` (in the `not()` selector).

Comment: "It's unclear what the purpose of this code is, but one way to solve it would be to exclude input[type="checkbox"] (in the not() selector)". As the input field values persist after the Ajax.BeginForm submit, the purpose of that script was to clear the form fields. But in the next form submit it'd  cause the problem as checkbox value was set to ''(an empty string).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for giving your time and bearing with me through the discussion.

Comment: No problem (and if I get bored one day, I'll rewrite this code for you :). As for _clearing the form fields_, then you should just be using `$('form').get(0).reset();`

Answer (score -1):

In MVC, when the checkbox is unchecked, it does not get added to the form elements and the modelstate.isvalid will always return false.

You have to add it explicitly with checked value as false. Can you check if you are getting any value in the controller action parameters list.

Comment: OP is using `CheckBoxFor()` which generates a hidden input for the property with `value="False"` You do NOT need to set it explicitly.

Comment: I guess it needs ChkFlag in the model directly and not in some object inside model